# hyperlink: link to page relative to a hypertarget

Tags: hyperref

I am trying to get a link to a page that is relative to a `hypertarget`. For example, in the MWE I would like to get one page after the link `chap2`, so that my link goes to the page after.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\hyperlink{chap2}{Here is the second page of chapter 2}  % What should go here?

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\hypertarget{chap2}{}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the [`afterpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) to your preamble and using

```
\afterpage{\phantomsection\hypertarget{chap2}{}}
```

will create a hypertarget at the top-left corner of the text block on the second page of the chapter:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref,lipsum,afterpage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\hyperlink{chap2}{Here is the second page of chapter 2}  % What should go here?

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\afterpage{\phantomsection\hypertarget{chap2}{}}% Hypertarget on p2 of chapter
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```